# NameError: name 'self' is not defined in Neural Network example

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm running the following code straight from Tariq Rashid's "Make Your Own Neural Network".  It says "NameError: name 'self' is not defined".  But it is defined.  The code is straight from the book.

```
import numpy

#neural network class definition
class neuralNetwork:

    #initialize the neural network
    def __init__(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate):
        # set number of nodes in each input, hidden, output layer
        self.inodes = inputnodes
        self.hnodes = hiddennodes
        self.onodes = outputnodes

        #learning rate
        self.lr = learningrate
        pass

    #train the neural network
    def train():
        pass

    #query the neural network
    def query():
        pass

#number of input, hidden and output nodes
input_nodes = 3
hidden_nodes = 3
output_nodes = 3

#learning rate is 0.3
learning_rate = 0.3

#create instance of neural network
n = neuralNetwork(input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes, learning_rate)

numpy.random.rand(3, 3)-0.5

#link weight matrices, wih and who
#weights inside the arrays are w_i_j, where link is from node i to node j in 
the next layer
#w11 w21
#w12 w22 etc
self.wih = (numpy.random.rand(self.hnodes, self.inodes) - 0.5)
self.who = (numpy.random.rand(self.onodes, self.hnodes) - 0.5)
```

Comment: replace 
```self.wih = (numpy.random.rand(self.hnodes, self.inodes) - 0.5)
self.who = (numpy.random.rand(self.onodes, self.hnodes) - 0.5)```


with 



```wih = (numpy.random.rand(n.hnodes, n.inodes) - 0.5)
who = (numpy.random.rand(n.onodes, n.hnodes) - 0.5)
print wih, who ```

will give you proper answer without any syntax errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is only defined inside the `__init__()` function here. Your code at the top level does not have it defined, hence the error.

Is the code meant to be inside a method in the `neuralNetwork` class - those empty `train()` and `query()` methods look suspicious.

Note that you will need to take `self` as an argument on methods. (e.g: `def train(self):`.

It looks like you are missing something about what the book is asking you to do. I'm assuming [this](https://github.com/makeyourownneuralnetwork/makeyourownneuralnetwork/blob/master/part2_neural_network.ipynb) is what you are attempting, and indeed that code is in the methods.

Comment: The empty train() and query() methods have yet to be filled in.  It is a step-by-step instruction.  I've been building it in a python notebook and that is the stage where I receive an error.

Comment: @Ken Indeed, but the code you are adding at the bottom needs to be in those methods. See the linked version. If you are referencing `self` you have to do it within a method, otherwise what does `self` mean? `self` refers to the current instance - if you aren't inside an instance, that is meaningless.

Comment: ok i see what you are saying.  i need to make sure the rest of that code is within the class. thank you.

Comment: @Ken Yeah. It's less obvious in this case because you only have one instance of the class, but if you made another one, using `self` outside doesn't make sense - because it could mean either one. It's worth noting that you can use `n` in the outside context to work with the instance (because that happens to be the name you have given it here), but in general, it makes way more sense to write the code as methods on the class and call those, otherwise it'll become hard to read and use.